# Select from two tables without using an OR

Tags: sql

I have two tables: **employee** and **department**

employee

```
name | salary | dNumber   
A    | 20000  | 1
B    | 25000  | 1
C    | 10000  | 5
D    | 10000  | 1
```

department

```
departmentName | departmentNumber
math           | 1
science        | 2
```

How can I select from these two tables without using boolean operators like OR & AND?

I want to find the employee that works for department 1 or has a salary greater than $20,000.

What I tried:

```
select name from employee

where salary>= 20000 from (where dNumber  in (select departmentNumber from department 
              where departmentNumber = 5));
```

That doesn't work because:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
```

Comment: Not using `or` or `and` is not your problem.  Your syntax is invalid. `from (where` is incorrect.  You need to understand how your tables join together.

Comment: Normal JOIN between the 2 tables and then self JOIN for each condition needed.Also take a look http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the requirement is to not use an `OR`, you could use `UNION` instead. Since you filter the department on its number, not on its name, you do not need the second table at all:

```
SELECT name FROM employee WHERE salary > 20000
    UNION
SELECT name FROM employee WHERE dNumber = 1
```

If you wanted to filter the department by name, a join or a subquery would be required:

```
SELECT name FROM employee WHERE salary > 20000
    UNION
SELECT name FROM employee e
JOIN department d ON e.dNumber=d.departmentNumber
WHERE departmentName = 'math'
```

Comment: So if `UNION` works like `OR` is there a way to this without using `UNION`? I know it is a bit ridiculous, but maybe there is away around it.

Comment: @J_Strauton You could also use a `CASE` expression to avoid an `OR`, but that is essentially the same thing: `SELECT name FROM employee WHERE (CASE WHEN salary > 20000 THEN 1 WHEN dNumber = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=1`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it:

```
select name from employee where where dnumber = 1
union
select name from employee where salary > 20000
```

Basically, union works like the OR operator and intersection works like the AND operator.